# Huge difference in process timing of functions (timit, time)

Tags: python-3.x, function, time

For some didactical purposes, I want to measure the timing of some functions (slightly more complex ones, than the ones shown) and discuss later on the big O scaling behaviour. But I have problems with the reliability of the numbers produced:

My code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def run_time(fun, runs):
    times = []
    for i in range(runs):
        t0 = time.clock() 
        fun()
        t1 = time.clock() - t0
        times.append(t1)
    return np.mean(times), np.std(times)#, times


def fact0(n):
    product = 1
    for i in range(n):
        product = product * (i+1)
    return product

def fact1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact1(n-1)

print(run_time(lambda: fact0(500), 100000))
print(run_time(lambda: fact1(500), 100000))
```

and I usually get something like:

```
(0.000186065330000082, 5.08689027009196e-05)
(0.0002853808799999845, 8.285739309454826e-05)
```

<s>So the std larger than the mean. That's awful for me. Furthermore I expected fact0() to be way faster than fact1() due to no recursion.</s>

If I now use timeit:

```
import timeit
mysetup = ""
mycode = ''' 
def fact1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact1(n-1)

fact1(500)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, stmt = mycode, number = 100000)/100000)
```

<s>I'll get something <s>almost an</s> order of magnt. smaller for mean:</s>

```
2.463713497854769e-07
```

After the below discussed corrections it is:

```
0.00028513264190871266
```

Which is in great accordance to the `run_time` version.

<s>So my question is how do I time functions appropriately? Why the huge difference between my two methods to get the timing? Any advices? I would love to stick to "time.clock()" and I don't want to use (again for didactical reasons) cProfile or even more complex modules.</s>

I am grateful for any comments...

(edited due to comments by @Carcigenicate)

Comment: Typo? You're never calling `fun` in `run_time`.

Comment: Don't I ? On line 5 of run_time between t0 = time.clock() and  t1 = time.clock() - t0. Is this not correct? The function is executed, though.

Comment: You need `fun()`. Just `fun` doesn't call it.

Comment: Wait, you're calling the function once before you give it to `run_time`. You need to pass the function itself, like `run_time(fact0, 10000)`. Right now, `run_time` is doing nothing 100,000 times. You'll need to wrap that in a lambda or something to supply arguments though. Something like `run_time(lambda: fact0(500, 10000)`. Fix both of those problems, and try it again.

Comment: Awesome. These two things worked out. I get now numbers of `(0.000186065330000082, 5.08689027009196e-05)
(0.0002853808799999845, 8.285739309454826e-05)
2.7136986143887043e-07`. So recursion is a factor of two slower. Thats what I expected. Still, why is `timeit`way off?

Comment: You never call the function in `mycode`. You're only timing how long it takes for the function to be defined.

Comment: Oh dear. Facepalm.. Thanks that was stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the function in `mycode`, so you're only timing how long it takes the function to be defined (which I would expect to be quite fast).

You need to call the function:

```
import timeit

mycode = ''' 
def fact1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact1(n-1)

fact1(100000)
'''

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=mycode, number=100000) / 100000)
```

Really though, this is suboptimal, since you're including in the timing the definition. I'd change this up and just pass a function:

```
def fact1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact1(n-1) 

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: fact1(100000), number=100000) / 100000)
```